# URL Encode PHP/Objective C

Tags: php, objective-c, url

I created an iPhone app which users search news, the app runs the search through a PHP script i wrote and uses Objective C string replace to take out all of the ',-_" symbols and replace them with + however i saw last night that a search had come through like this: "Beyonc%C3%A8" i was just wondering what this meant, its clearly trying to be Beyonce, but has someone used an accent over the 'e' and screwed the URL up?

Comment: You are right: "Beyonc%C3%A8" == "Beyoncè" // **EDIT**: I forgot to copy the link how to solve that in Objective C: http://blog.evandavey.com/2009/01/how-to-url-encode-nsstring-in-objective-c.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's more to URL encoding than "+" signs.  Most of it is percent escaping.

In addition to replacing "+" with " ", you should also do this.

```
NSString *decodedString = [encodedString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```